# AppId for iPhone

Tags: iphone

What does an AppId actually consists of ..
com.mycompany.applicationname.

i) does this applicationname(right last one) should be the same as of the name .app binary to be submitted to the Appstore.

ii) is there  any way to change the appname after submitting it to the appstore once.

Answer (score 1):

This question is already answered on [StackOverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com).

i) It's a unique identifier, your company's domain name (reversed) followed by the app name.  This was [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555424/what-is-the-app-id-that-the-apple-developer-connection-site-is-asking-me-for) over on SO.  There are more details on [Apple's Developer Connect site](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/bundles/howto.action).

ii) No, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996477/removing-app-id-from-developer-connection) on SO.

Comment: BTW, it doesn't have to be the company domain reversed, that is Apple's recommendation.  It just has to be unique worldwide among all developers.  You can also use wildcard's, ie: com.apple.*